# Принцип раздления интерфейсов для CRUD операций

Tags: c#, интерфейс, solid

Вопрос достаточно простой. Стоит ли создать один интерфейс, для всех CRUD операций, или стоит оставить по интерфейсу для каждого типа операции.

Всего 4 интерфейса (Создание, Чтение, Обновление, Удаление) и 4 класса для каждого из интерфейсов. Или же создать один интерфейс который будет содержать все CRUD операции, и один класс который будет реализовывать все эти интерфейсы (Методов в этих классах итого 13), не будет ли это противоречить ISP ?

Сейчас у меня вот это выстроено так (Извините за скриншоты, если они тут неуместны):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот в таком виде это находится в контейнере зависимостей :

```
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICreateUser, CreateUser>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IDeleteUser, DeleteUser>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IReadUser, ReadUser>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IUpdateUser, UpdateUser>();
```

P.S Если я чего-то не указал, то укажите что именно, не нужно сразу даунвоутить.

Comment: Отделить чтение (read) от остальных операций имеет смысл. Гляньте CQS и CQRS если не знакомы. Стоит ли разделять три других операции - думаю, это вопрос вкуса.

Comment: Примечание: название папки/неймспейса `IPostgres`, имхо, неудачное. Ведь это _общие_ интерфейсы для работы с данными. Они не должны ссылаться на _конкретное_ хранилище. А вот _реализации_ делаются для конкретной СУБД, будь то Postgres, MySql, Mongo.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, завтра гляну CQS, CQRS. Также название папок планировал менять, но все равно спасибо. @AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Плюсую разделение только в случае `CQRS` и т.п. Если у вас чтением занимается один микросервис, а остальными операциями другой, то делить интерфейсы нужно, а если нет, то обычно это одна сущность "репозиторий" и зачем её тогда делить, непонятно.

Comment: Вместо скриншота дерева папок можно показать его в текстовом виде воспользовавшись утилитой типа `tree`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Принцип разделения интерфейсов для CRUD или прочих операций лежит в плоскости понимания принципа. Вы разделяете интерфейс по необходимости, а необходимость разделения возникает тогда когда появляется методы заглушки т.е. если вы не собираетесь имплементировать тот или иной метод интерфейса. И в вашем случае если имплементация CRUD не будет содержать чтение то можно разделить, но я бы не стал даже при реализации CQRS делить потому что ничто не мешает мне реализовать его через паттерн Фасад.